# Creating click action in html by js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

trying to create reaction on span or element with id(in my example id=reset) (on.click) action. 
tried to find my element by getElementByID or .find or just .click but it doesnt work... maybe its because the thing I want to press is a child of a child of a child... I'm not sure, thanks for help... The proper question is: How my btnClick function should look to work properly?

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MIB2/MIB2+ Tool</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="js/controler.js"></script>
    <script src="js/chartist.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" role="tablist">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-address="ip-info.php" data-role="targets">
                available targets
            </a>
        </li>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid well-lg">
    <div id="targetInformation" class="container">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my ip-info.php:

```
echo'
<div class=" col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <span id="reset" title="Power Switch" class=" pull-right hover glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" style="cursor: pointer;" aria-hidden="true">
                </span>
            </h3>

        </div>
    <div class="panel-body text-center">';
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
```

my controler.JS:

```
var TargetInformation = [
    'ip':'1.2.3.4',
    'ip':'5.6.7.8'
]

var SCRIPT = {
    init : function(){
        this.clickOnMenu();
    },
    clickOnMenu: function(){
        $("ul.nav a").on('click',function() {
                            $("#targetInformation").html(''); // clean screen
                            var role = $(this).data('role');
                            switch(role) {
                                case 'targets':
                                    for(i=0; i< TargetInformation.length; i++) {
                                        $.get( $(this).data('address'), {'ip':TargetInformation[i]}, function (data) {
                                            $("#targetInformation").append(data);
                                        });
                                    }
    }
}
var aaa = {
    btnClick: function()
    {
        $(document).find("#reset").on('click',function() {
            console.log('hello');
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready( function(){
    SCRIPT.init();
    aaa.btnClick();
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your btnClick function-

```
$('html').on('click', "#reset", function() {
            console.log('hello');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code is that, when `aaa.btnClick()` is being called, there is no element with id reset, so it is ignored from attached events. Remove `aaa.btnClick()` from your `.ready` and place it in php or after the get. You can try something like this:

In the js file, add a global variable to make sure you don't add the same event again and again. Something like: `var clickedOnce = false;`

Then change your for loop as,

```
for(i=0; i< TargetInformation.length; i++) {
     $.get( $(this).data('address'), {'ip':TargetInformation[i]}, function (data) {
         $("#targetInformation").append(data);
         if(clickedOnce == false){aaa.btnClick(); clickedOnce=true;}
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are clicking an `<a>` try to prevent the default event. Also change the way that you are attaching your event, use id as a selector

```
btnClick: function()
    {
        $("#reset").click(function() {
            console.log('hello');
        });
    }
```

Comment: I dont get it why it attaches an even on the same button? 
clickOnMenu is a top menu with <a> elements

btnClick is inside so its different thing.. or not?